# JetBrain Rider: viewing List<> during debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, rider

I'm trying to view the content of a List<> during debugging. Unfortunately I can't see them, cause I get the following message within the variables window:

> corvalue.GetExactTypeSafe(out type). The object is in a 
>   zombie state. (Exception of HRESULT: 0x8013134F). The error code is
>   CORDBG_E_OBJECT_NEUTERED, or 0x8013134F.

Does someone know what this means and how I can view the List<>? It's no compilation error cause I can normally run through the code.

Comment: I think debugger cannot access to the variable in the moment you try to see it content because the parent tread is in zombie state, is that possible? [her you can find a long explanation of the problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigskibo/2003/10/10/reference-counting-garbage-collection-and-zombies-oh-my/).

Answer (score -1):

sounds like you are using multi-threading. lets start with `zombie state`.
`zombie state` is when a thread that was previously started (by another thread) finally finished it work. and additionally this thread didn't return the control to the calling thread. hence, this thread is currently ain't doing anything although it wasn't terminated.This is the source of the name, the thread ain't alive and ain't dead.  For more information you can check this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164039/what-is-a-zombie-process-or-thread).
You need to simply free up all allocated resources by restarting your program or kill the parent thread\process.
 If you keep having the issue in the "interesting code" You can also try to run your program with out multi threading to ensure you wouldn't encounter any zombies along the way. (:

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. 

How can I run a program not with multithreading? Is this Rider specific? Cause in VS I can view the collection without problems...

Greetings

Comment: I meant you can just temporary transform the interesting area to a single threaded code. If it is only for  debugging.

Comment: I don't think this post answers the original question. I placed the bounty on the question for a solution to viewing the variables in RIder's debugger. VS has no problem showing their value. This answer is just an explanation of what zombie state is (not the question) and a suggestion to rewrite code to not use multithreading (not possible in my case nor a solution to the issue).